# ZFTool não funciona, retorna o html da aplicação [Zend Framework]

Tags: php, zend, zend-framework-2, php-5

Olá, estou tentando usar o zftools (terminal) para criar módulos pra o Zend mas ao contrário do esperado que seria uma mensagem de erro ou sucesso o zf.php imprime na tela o HTML da aplicação, como se eu estivesse no navegador.

Comandos usados:

> composer require zendframework/zftool:dev-master
>
> vendor/bin/zf.php create module Teste

Comment: Ambiente Windows ou Linux? Qual o HTML retornado?

Comment: Linux, retorna o HTML da página padrão do zend pós instalado, aquela com links de doc etc que a gente vê normalmente ao abrir a aplicação pelo navegador, estou executando as ferramentas mas é como se ele efetivamente executasse a aplicação de fato.